# Read/write to stream with JavaCV

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm trying to make use of JavaCV for android. I would like to create a video stream composed of screenshots. I found out that I can write a file using FFmpegFrameRecorder, but I can't write to a stream, array, buffer, or anything else, other than a file.

Next thing is that I found a piece of code featuring custom FrameRecorder using 'avio_alloc_context' and read/write/seek callbacks. Unfortunately it's only a snippet and it's in C++. 'avio_alloc_context' method on android takes Read_packet, Read_packet and Seek callbacks, so I cannot pass a Write_packet callback. Moreover, right after 'avio_alloc_context' call, I get 'finalize' called on all objects passed to 'avio_alloc_context'.

```
final VideoOutputStream videoOutputStream = new VideoOutputStream(stream);

Read_packet read_packet = new Read_packet() {
    @Override
    public int call(Pointer arg0, BytePointer arg1, int arg2) {
        VideoOutputStream videoStream = (VideoOutputStream) arg0;
        try {
            videoStream.write(arg1.getStringBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arg2;
    }
};

AVIOContext pb = avio_alloc_context(new MBytePointer(av_malloc(video_outbuf_size)), video_outbuf_size, 1,videoOutputStream, null, read_packet, null);

oc.pb(pb);
```

Using the above code nothing crashes nor reports errors. I just keep getting empty files.

My question is - does anyone of you guys managed to get it working? Do you know a correct way to initialize custom reading/writing in FrameRecorder/Grabber in JavaCV?

Comment: Can you try to do the same on the desktop with the JDK? It's probably going to be easier to debug. At the very least, we're going to get some error message if it doesn't work...

Comment: I wrote it on desktop in C++ and then ported it to android using JNI. It's ugly, but there's a plenty of C++ samples over the internet, so it's quite easy to get the code working.

Comment: Right, but it should work with JavaCPP in the way you wrote it... I mistakenly compiled with Read_packet, but the signature of Write_packet is the same, so it should still work. Actually, it would need an `allocate()`, which is missing, to work. I'll be fixing that

Comment: These changes should fix that: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/detail?r=06b8aa39df97e0f713b1b6bef5197487e8952830